# Create custom wordpress page after install my custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

How to create custom wordpress page after install my custom integration wordpress plugin.
Ex : (If we have install Woocommerce it's automatically create the cart & checkout & myaccount page). I need like some format.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new page on plugin activation hook in your plugin

```
function add_my_custom_page() {
    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'My Custom Page' ),
      'post_content'  => 'My custom page content',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_my_custom_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to your plugin
It will check that a page with the same name does not exist.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'custom_plugin_activation' );

function custom_plugin_activation() {
  if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) return;
  global $wpdb;
  if ( null === $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT post_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_name = 'new-page-slug'", 'ARRAY_A' ) ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // create post object
    $page = array(

      'post_title'  => __( 'New Page' ),

      'post_status' => 'publish',

      'post_author' => $current_user->ID,

      'post_type'   => 'page',

    );
    // insert the post into the database

    wp_insert_post( $page );
  }
}
```

Here is a full list of parameters accepted by the [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function.